# Two dimensional comparison in sql

Tags: sql, hana

DB schema

```
CREATE TABLE newsletter_status
(
    cryptid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(25),
    regDat timestamp,
    confirmDat timestamp,
    updateDat timestamp,
    deleteDat timestamp
);
```

There are rows with the same `cryptid`, I need to squash them to one row. So the `cryptid` becomes effectively unique. The complexity comes from the fact that I need to compare dates by rows as well as by columns. How to implement that?

The rule I need to use is:

- status should be taken from the row with the latest timestamp (among all 4 dates)
- for every date column I need to select the latest date

Example:

```
002bc5 | new         | 2010.01.15 | 2001.01.15 | NULL       | 2020.01.10
002bc5 | confirmed   | NULL       | 2020.01.30 | 2020.01.15 | 2020.01.15
002bc5 | deactivated | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | 2020.12.03
```

needs to be squashed into:

```
002bc5 | deactivated | 2010.01.15 | 2020.01.30 | 2020.01.15 | 2020.12.03
```

The status `deactivated` is taken because the timestamp 2020.12.03 is the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to get the status is to sort rowset by dates in descending order. In Oracle there is `agg_func(<arg>) keep (dense_rank first ...)`, in other databases it can be replaced with `row_number()` and filter. Because analytic functions in HANA works not so good sometimes, I suggest to use the only one aggregate function I know in HANA that supports ordering inside - `STRING_AGG` - with little trick. If you have not a thousands of rows with statuses (i.e. concatenated status will not be greater 4000 for varchar), it will work. This is the query:

```
select
  cryptid,
  max(regDat) as regDat,
  max(confirmDat) as confirmDat,
  max(updateDat) as updateDat,
  max(deleteDat) as deleteDat,
  substr_before(
    string_agg(status, '|'
      order by greatest(
        ifnull(regDat, date '1000-01-01'),
        ifnull(confirmDat, date '1000-01-01'),
        ifnull(updateDat, date '1000-01-01'),
        ifnull(deleteDat, date '1000-01-01')
      ) desc),
    '|'
  ) as status
from newsletter_status
group by cryptid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select cryptid,
       coalesce(max(case when status = 'deactivated' then status end)
                max(case when status = 'confirmed' then status end),
                max(case when status = 'new' then status end),
               ) as status,
       max(regDat),
       max(confirmDat),
       max(updateDat),
       max(deleteDat)
from newsletter_status
group by cryptid;
```

The `coalesce()`s are a trick to get the statuses in priority order.

EDIT:

If you just want the row with the latest timestamp:

```
select cryptid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) as status_on_max_date,
       max(regDat),
       max(confirmDat),
       max(updateDat),
       max(deleteDat)
from (select ns.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cryptid
                                order by greatest(coalesce(regDat, '2000-01-01'),
                                              coalesce(confirmDat, '2000-01-01'),
                                               coalesce(updateDat, '2000-01-01'),
                                               coalesce(deleteDat, '2000-01-01')
                                         )
                               ) as seqnum
                      
      from newsletter_status ns
     ) ns
group by cryptid;
```

Comment: This is definetely a new cool feature to know. But it seems to be NOT what I want. I need the status be taken from the row with the latest timestamp. "deactivated" is not a final state. You can reactivate an entry. 'deactivated' becomes 'new'.

Comment: OP needs the status from the row, where some timestamp has the maximum value: `greatest(max(regDat),
       max(confirmDat),
       max(updateDat),
       max(deleteDat))`

Comment: @SGTechEdge . . . I like my interpretation better -- even though your question is quite clear.  I updated the answer.  In most databases `greatest()` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`, so the expression is complicated by needed `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by ranking the rows of each `cryptid` by the greatest value of the date column. Then we can use that information to identify the latest status per `cryptid`, and aggregate :

```
select cryptid, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then status end) as status,
    max(regDate) as regDat,
    max(confirmDat) as confirmDat,
    max(updatedDat) as updatedDat,
    max(deleteDat) as deleteDat
from (
    select ns.*, 
        row_number() over(
            partition by cryptid 
            order by greatest(
                coalesce(regDate,    '0001-01-01'), 
                coalesce(confirmDat, '0001-01-01'),
                coalesce(updatedDat, '0001-01-01'), 
                coalesce(deleteDat,  '0001-01-01')
            )
        ) rn 
    from newsletter_status ns
) ns
group by cryptid
```

Comment: This looks really good. Thank you. I nned to test it tmr at work.

Comment: suddenly this fails on the dataset (abcd, confirmed, NULL, 2014-11-29 11:00:00, 2014-11-29 11:00:00, NULL), (abcd, new, 2015-10-29 11:00:00, NULL, 2015-10-29 11:00:00, NULL). Dates are correct, but the resulting status after using your sql is 'confirmed', should be 'new'.